# How to find a locale name for a given character encoding?

Tags: locale, character-encoding

The man page for [`setlocale`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setlocale) seems to say that the language code and the character encoding name are sufficient to set the appropriate locale:

> A locale name is typically of the form language[_territory][.codeset][@modifier], where language is an ISO 639 language code, territory is an ISO 3166 country code, and codeset is a character set or encoding identifier like ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8.

However, a quick test shows that only the "modifier" part of a locale name is optional:

```
void tryLocale(const char * locid)
{
    char * result = std::setlocale(LC_CTYPE, locid);
    std::cout << locid << " = " << (result ? result : "fail") << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    tryLocale("de");           // de = fail
    tryLocale("de_DE");        // de_DE = fail
    tryLocale("de_DE.CP1252"); // de_DE.CP1252 = de_DE.CP1252
    tryLocale("de.CP1252");    // de.CP1252 = fail
    tryLocale(".CP1252");      // .CP1252 = fail
}
```

My problem is that I only know the desired encoding name (e.g. `ISO-8859-1`) and I may come up with the language code (e.g. `en`). I have no idea how to find an appropriate country name (e.g. `US`), and I'm not interested in a country anyway: I just want functions like `tolower` in my app to use the correct codepage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'll have to loop through them. In `zsh`:

```
for l (${(f)"$(locale -a)"}) 
  [[ $(LC_ALL=$l locale charmap) = ISO-8859-1 ]] && print -r -- $l
```

Or the same using its `$langinfo` special associative array in the `zsh/langinfo` module:

```
zmodload zsh/langinfo
for LC_ALL (${(f)"$(locale -a)"})
  [[ $langinfo[CODESET] = ISO-8859-1 ]] && print -r -- $LC_ALL
```

Would list all the available locale that use ISO-8859-1 as the charmap.

But note that the `LC_CTYPE` category where the charmap / codeset is specified also covers character classification: what is a lower case letter, what is punctuation, etc and also transliterations (like that used by `tolower()`), both of which could vary from one region / country to the next even if the same codeset is used.

For instance, see how lowercase `I` is `ı` in GNU Turkish locales, regardless of what charmap is being used (UTF-8, ISO-8859-9...), while it's `i` in most other locales that also use UTF-8.

You can have a look at the locale source definitions, for instance with:

```
(cd /usr/share/i18n/locales && pcregrep -Me '(?ms)^LC_CTYPE.*?^END' -- *)
```

On a GNU system to see the differences across locales for the `LC_CTYPE` category. You won't find the charmap in there, locales for combinations of those files and charmaps are generated using `localedef -i thosefiles -f charmap`, though only some combinations make sense, see `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED` for the list.

For instance, the `en_GB` locale on your system might have been generated with `localedef -i locales/en_GB -f charmaps/ISO-8859-1.gz` and the `en_GB.UTF-8` one with `localedef -i locales/en_GB -f charmaps/UTF-8.gz`.

So here, maybe you need to find a locale that uses `ISO-8859-1` as the charmap, but also with transliteration rules and character classifications that make sense in mainland Britain for British English or for German speakers in Italy / Germany etc, like for instance that satisfy:

```
[[ $(locale language)  = 'British English' &&
   $(locale territory) = 'United Kingdom' &&
   $(locale charmap)   = ISO-8859-1 ]]
```

Which should narrow the choice somewhat.

Note that `language` and `territory` are non-standard GNU extensions, which explains why you won't find them in zsh's `$langinfo`. The GNU libc documentation (`info libc langinfo`) only mentions:

> The file ‘langinfo.h’ defines a lot more symbols but none of them
> are official.  Using them is not portable, and the format of the
> return values might change.  Therefore we recommended (sic) you not use
> them.

`/usr/include/langinfo.h` on my system has:

```
  _NL_IDENTIFICATION_LANGUAGE,
  _NL_IDENTIFICATION_TERRITORY,
```

See also `locale -k LC_IDENTIFICATION`, `locale -k LC_CTYPE` for the list of keywords supported for a given locale category on GNU systems (`locale -kc LC_ALL` used to work but no longer does these days apparently).

Comment: Thanks. After reading your answer and a few other sources I came to the conclusion that the only way to deal with several encodings in a software is to include encoding functions in it. Locale is useful if the software needs to support only the encoding chosen by the user for their system.

Comment: See also standard UNIX `iconv`(1) and `iconv`(3) as well for charset conversions. Or the more advanced ones from ICU or `perl`

Comment: That's exactly what I meant by "to include encoding functions in the software" - that is," to build against an i18n library", not necessarily "to write my own encoding functions".